# How to get country from location id in facebook api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the current scope for a user login:
`'scope' => 'public_profile,email,user_about_me,user_location,publish_actions'`

When a user login in my site, i get location as an array which contains only the `id` and the `name`.

How do i get the `state` and `country` from the `id`?

I have tried making a `get` request to `graph.facebook.com/<id>` but it returns me the same data, i.e. `id` and `name`.

Here is the id: `106069382765976`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Since API v2.0, you need to *ask* for the fields you want, otherwise you will only get a few default fields (usually id and name.)
2. The user location itself is a Page object - so you need to request the location of that again.

Combine the two, and you get `106069382765976?fields=location`

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=106069382765976%3Ffields%3Dlocation&version=v2.8